# How to use WebKitBrowser in C # console application

Tags: c#

I use WebKitBrowser (http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/). Control works great in my winform application when I add into the application with style drag-and–drop from toolbox.

If I tried tried it in consol application, it didn´t work. If I entered URL web page, it has never been uploaded.

In the constructor I created instance WebKitBrowser and then I called method Navigate (). I think that loading page has never started.

My code look like this:

```
private readonly WebKit.WebKitBrowser _webKitBrowser;

public DemoApplication()
{           
_webKitBrowser = new WebKit.WebKitBrowser();
_webKitBrowser.DocumentCompleted += WebKitBrowserDocumentCompleted;
_webKitBrowser.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
}

void WebKitBrowserDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // it never gets here.
var sourceCode = _webKitBrowser.DocumentText;
}
```

Does anybody know where is the problem? Can you use this WebKitBrowser for this case?

Comment: If the WebKitBrowser class is a `Control`, and is intended to be used on a Form, what makes you think it's going to work outside of a form/control heirarchy?

Comment: Yes, but this code does not work in a WinForm application as well. Loading of the page works only if I add a component by using drag-and-drop from toolbox which seems strange to me. It seems that component works only in the moment  when it is visible in window form.

Comment: Yeah, because the control needs to be set up within the form's control heirarchy. You can't just execute this code behind a form and expect it to do something, because you didn't add it to an existing control container. The same goes for a console app.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you. But if I use standard WebBrowser control exactly in the same way, which is included in .Net, then it works properly. Also in the console application. So that´s why I thought that it should be the same also in WebKitBrowser.

Comment: The `WebBrowser` control was created by a team at Microsoft, and the `WebKitBrowser` is a port of a third party browser library. There is nothing that says they have to work the same.

Comment: `WebBrowser` control works in a console application? outside a window Form? really? please show an example. As @JirkaPenzes says, your code does not work because you create a WebBrowser control but don't add it to Control collection(look at all generated code when you drag and drop a control on a form)